# Limit, Sum, and Natural Log

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need some help completing this problem. Prove or disprove that the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\ln(n)\right).$$

What I have done so far:

Write

$$\ln(n)=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\mathrm{dx}}{{x}},$$

let $P$ be the partition $\{x_{1}=1,2,\ldots,x_{n}=n\}$. Then, the upper estimate of the integral over $P$ is given by

$$U(P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{n},$$

and the lower estimate of the integral is given by

$$L(P) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}-1.$$

Then, since $U(P) \ge \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x} \ge L(P)$, we end up with

$$\frac{1}{n} \le \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\ln(n) \le 1.$$

Taking the limit as n goes to infinity gives us
$$0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\ln(n)\right) \le 1.$$

Any recommendations on where to go from here, or a different approach to the problem, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that the sequence $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} - \ln(n)$ has an upper and lower bound. But this does not imply convergence. Hint: Show that $S_n$ is monotone and then you are done.

Comment: I've always liked using two sides; $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\ln(n)$ starts a little high and decreases. $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}-\ln(n+1)$ starts a little low but increases. Hope I have it right this time.

Answer (score 1):

Summing the inequalities
$$
\log(j+1)-\log(j)=\int_j^{j+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\le\frac1j\le\int_{j-1}^j\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x=\log(j)-\log(j-1)\tag{1}
$$
gives
$$
\log(n+1)=\int_1^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\le\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1j\le1+\int_1^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x=1+\log(n)\tag{2}
$$
and subtracting $\log(n)$ from $(2)$ yields
$$
0\le\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1j-\log(n)\le1\tag{3}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
a_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1j-\log(n)=1+\sum_{j=2}^n\overbrace{\left(\frac1j-(\log(j)-\log(j-1))\right)}^{\le\,0\text{ by }(1)}\tag{4}
$$
$(3)$ and $(4)$ say that $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence that is bounded below by $0$.

Comment: Clean and concise. +1